# Ubuntu 10.04 can't boot, kernel panic

Tags: ubuntu, libraries, kernel-panic

I downloaded [pcap source](http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.0.0.tar.gz) compiled it and got a lib ending in libsomething.so.1.21.1. I tried to find how to install a lib online and in my impatience did the following

```
sudo .install-sh /lib libsomething.1.21.1
```

The output was the following

```
install-sh :250:chmod not found

install-sh : 1: rm :not found
```

After this I could not launch any program or shell command at the prompt in the terminal(I could use cd but not ls or others). Now when I try to boot into Ubuntu I get a kernel panic after the following line:

```
run-init:/sbin/init: No such file or directory.
```

.install-sh is in the pcap folder, source was taken directly from the website.

I don't have a clue as to what the script did, I would be very thankful if somebody could give me any pointers on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what I think happened is that the script moved `/lib` to `libsomething.1.21.1` (in the directory where you were when you ran the script). After that, pretty much nothing worked. Every dynamically linked executable relies on the [dynamic loader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/cant-execute-some-binaries-in-chroot-environment-zsh-not-found/13409#13409), which lives in `/lib`: move that and you're in trouble.

[It is possible to recover from moving `/lib`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17428/moved-bin-and-other-folders-how-to-get-them-back/17448#17448), but your system is now unbootable. You need to repair it from some other bootable media (a live CD or DVD).

Repairing should be simple, because moving away `/lib` means there was no opportunity for further damage. Just find which directory you were in and move back `/path/to/libsomething.1.21.1` to `/lib`.

In unix circles, the source almost always comes before the destination, when copying or moving stuff.

For future reference, don't install home-built binaries in `/lib`. Files in `/bin`, `/lib`, `/sbin` and `/usr` (except `/usr/local`) are managed by your distribution. The directory `/usr/local` is for your own stuff; install your non-packaged libraries in `/usr/local/lib`, your non-packaged executables in `/usr/local/bin` and so on.

Comment: Sorry, did not see your response, you are right, the lib folder was moved to folder from where I was trying to install the library.I will try to copy it back and report result.

Comment: Thanks, your method worked, I am able to boot into the system and almost everything is working fine, graphics are working, but sound , wifi and other devices etc are not working, any suggestions. Is there a method to extract drivers or packages from CD,( I had like to avoid to boot 10.04 ubuntu from usb) and have them installed to get stuff working properly.

Comment: @AquaAsh It looks like you've got `/lib` back but `/lib/modules` (which contains the drivers that are not essential to booting) is somehow missing or corrupted. What entries do you see in `/lib/modules`? What does `du -s /lib/modules/*` show? The entry corresponding to the kernel you're running (`uname -r`) should have about 100MB. If the drivers are missing and don't seem to have been moved elsewhere, reinstall the `linux-image-…` package, something like `apt-get --reinstall install linux-image-2.6.32-37-generic`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it did an `rm -fr`, i.e. deleted everything.  Boot from some other media and see what's left of the system, if anything.

Comment: I booted from a usb and everything is not deleted, there are files, folders, profiles, even the sbin folder is there, user files etc are also present.

Comment: @AquaAsh, and what about /sbin/init?

Comment: The init file in sbin is present. Though, I seem to be missing the whole lib folder, what do you recommend.

Comment: @AquaAsh, that explains it.. if you wiped out your lib directory then you will need to restore it from backup or reinstall.

Comment: I tried copying lib folder from another machine, but it does not seem to work, anyway I am going to install Linux mint and be done with it. Thanks for your help.