# Undo `mv` command?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moved bin and other folders! How to get them back?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17428/moved-bin-and-other-folders-how-to-get-them-back)

I entered the following command, which I know is not correct and I think I've moved everything to "../", can I do anything to recover from this:

```
mv /* ../
```

Comment: This will surely make you consider backups. I suggest Areca :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you screwed up. :) Everyone does it at some point. As you said, you've moved everything to `../` (if you were root).

Without knowing what directory you were in at the time, you might have a chance of getting things back to some reasonable state by typing `../bin/mv ../* /` from the same directory.

Otherwise, you can boot from a [recovery CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) so you can back up your data, and then reinstall Linux.

While booting from the recovery CD, you could also try moving the root files and directories back to `/`. That way you might be able to avoid reinstalling.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help, looks like im going to have to go the recovery route!

Comment: @shellter `/bin/mv` was moved to a new directory so it is no longer in `/bin/`. Besides using the new location you typically also have to create `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` containing your new lib directories.

Comment: doah! I remove my hare-brained comment. (I didn't know it was possible to move stuff above/beyond '/'. ) Good luck to all.

Comment: @UlrichDangel Not just that, you also need to invoke the dynamic linker explicitly. See the duplicate question.

Comment: @VinceAshby-Smith This is in fact fairly simple to fix once you know what commands to run **as long as you still have a root shell open**.

Answer (score 0):

If you had busybox already installed, you may have some success with:

```
../bin/busybox mv ../* /
```

after that, you can then manually clean up the stuff that should have been in ../ (wherever that is) back from / to wherever it belongs.

busybox has a chance of working where mv doesn't because busybox is linked statically and does not need to dynamically link any libraries.

If busybox wasn't already installed, you could try to boot a rescue CD, mount your hard disk partitions under /mnt, and mv stuff to where it belongs.