# Moved some files unable to use mv now

Tags: shell, centos, root-filesystem

I accidently  used `mv mymods /* *` . Now i am unable to undo it or either use any command. How do i fix that?

I was in directory name `/home/nginx/crap`

```
[root@somehost /home/nginx/crap]# mv mymods /* *
```

**Centos 6.3 
user - root**

Directory Structure of `/home/nginx/crap`

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5493666

Comment: Did you do it as root?

Comment: yes. I did it as root!

Comment: How did you manage to post that list on *gist* from a remote system where no commands work?

Comment: I have some folder in my pc too. So i used that.

Comment: I am able to boot into recovery mode. But from there how can i fix this , so my server is able to boot like before without need to reinstall OS.

Comment: If you'd moved the entries in `/` to a different directory and still had a running shell, you could have recovered: [Moved bin and other folders! How to get them back?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17428/moved-bin-and-other-folders-how-to-get-them-back)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That command would have resulted in:

1. File or folder `/home/nginx/crap/mymods`
2. All directories at `/` *(in theory)*
3. All files and directories in `/home/nginx/crap/`

moved into last directory given by `*` in `/home/nginx/crap/`. As in:

```
ls -d /home/nginx/crap/*
afile1 afile2 dir1 dir2
```

Then everything would be put into `dir2`.

If the last entry of `*` was a file the command would have failed as you cannot
move files and folders into a file.

As the last file in your `gist` post is `tree.txt` you most likely did not move
any files – and something else has happened.

See if you have the `env` command available.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely moved the files at `/*`, which is essentially everything, given `/` is the top level directory and you move everything, `*`, under it. I guess my question would be where did you move it to?

You might be able to move everything back if you can figure out where you moved it to. You'll have to call the `mv` command directly (ie. `/accident/dir/mv`) given it's now in some other location, and there is no guarantees you'll be able to even run it given that any libraries it might need aren't where they're suppose to be either.

I would suggest booting the system using the rescue CD capability that comes with the CentOS CD/DVD and allowing it to mount your HDD. From there you should be able to use the Live CD's `mv` command to repair your HDD's Linux installation.

Comment: I was in directory /home/nginx/crap , then i issued that command which messed up things. Any idea?

Comment: Yeah so everything is most likely in that directory. I'd still use a rescue CD to effect repairs.

Comment: That's a dedicated server hosted at OVH. I don't know, how to boot it via live cd.

Comment: See if the `mv` command is under that path then would be your next option. It's going to be most like here: `/home/nginx/crap/bin/mv`.

Comment: This might be helpful, it's OVH's tips for restoring deleted files: http://help.ovh.co.uk/BackupsOnPlanWeb